# How to create project in Julia and Juno?

Tags: julia, project, juno-ide

I've installed Julia, Atom and Juno. I used to think that before you start coding anything you should create a project, but I can't find "New Project" item in Juno IDE.

Does Julia support the notion of project? If yes, how could I create a simple project, add Julia files to it, run it, etc?

Comment: Yes, Julia actually support projects, look at the keyword "generate", directly in Julia. Creating a project allow you to keep the package version all along devellopement. Hope someone can be more precise, as I'm only a beginner with Julia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - in Julia the concepts "project" and "package" are essentially synonymous - you'll follow the same folder structure, assign a license etc. Currently, the best way of starting a new project is to use the PkgTemplates.jl package (https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl). To work with projects in Julia I'd greatly recommend reading the project documentation: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/

None of this is unfortunately implemented in Juno yet, but there is an open issue for it: https://github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl/issues/175

Answer (score 22):

If you're just looking for a simple way to get the equivalent of a Python virtual environment, where all your packages are contained to a project, here's how I'm currently doing it:

**Setting up a new environment**:

1. `mkdir myproject`
2. `cd myproject`
3. `julia`
4. `]`
5. `activate .` # Now it should say (myproject) pkg> as the prompt
6. `add DataFrames` # (for example)
7. Now two files will appear in myproject/

   1. Project.toml - lists all packages installed. Kind of like a requirements.txt file in Python
   2. Manifest.toml - lists all packages required/available in the project. More intense and complete than Project.toml.

**Initializing an environment based on a Project.toml file**:

1. `using Pkg`
2. `Pkg.activate(".")`
3. `Pkg.instantiate()` # this will install the packages listed in Project.toml

(You can also use the `]` method at the REPL)

Note that if you just do `Pkg.activate()` (no "."), then it activates the base environment. Usually you won't want to activate the base environment if you're trying to set up an environment specific to a certain project folder.